# Clearing content of empty cells in column A

Tags: excel, vba

Please may i ask for your help. My advanced filter does not work as the column A has non visible content in empty cell. In order to make it work, I need VBa code which will select all cells from A7 to A200 and clear content of only blank cells.

Comment: Are the blanks the result of a formula, so they contain `=""` or something?

Comment: Yes the blanks are result of a formula, however if I try with ="" it gives me 0 which would then filter only cells containing "0" and not blanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have **formula** cells in column **1** that are returning *Null* and you want to clear them:

```
Sub ClearAlmostMothing()
    Dim rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        For Each r In rng
            If r.Value = "" Then r.ClearContents
        Next r
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

**NOTES:**

- using `OnError` avoids problems if the column is already "clean"
- using `ClearContents` leaves the cell format alone.

**EDIT#1:**

This version is slightly faster on my computer:

```
Sub ClearAlmostMothing2()
    Dim rng As Range, rClear As Range
    Set rClear = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rng = Range("A7:A400").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        For Each r In rng
            If r.Value = "" Then
                If rClear Is Nothing Then
                    Set rClear = r
                Else
                    Set rClear = Union(rClear, r)
                End If
            End If
        Next r
        rClear.ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary, Your code actually worked so many thanks. The only issue I am having is that it takes bit longer to run this code, is there is way to reduce the run time. Would appreciate your help again.

Comment: @NashPeters  It **might** be possible to speed it up a little.........check back in a couple of hours.

Comment: Hi Gary, Many thanks again, I will wait, really appreciate your support.

Comment: @NashPeters  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the edited version however this formula is not clearing blank cell, it doesn't work as the previous one you had posted.

Comment: @NashPeters  The new code only goes down to **A400**

Answer (score 2):

Just use `SpecialCells`:

```
Range("A7:A200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, however when i use this code it gives me run time error 1004.

Comment: Are you positive there are blanks? If there are formulas in there that result in a blank, i.e. `=If(1+1=3,"Wrong math","")` results in effectively `=""`, that is *not* considered a blank.

Comment: Thanks again, you are right the blank cell is derived from the formula =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(AS:AS="",NA(),AS:AS),'Receiving Report'!B:G,5,FALSE),"") , I ma presuming the cell should be blank but seems it is not in this case. How do I get around it, sorry I my knowledge is still intermediate in excel.

Comment: @NashPeters - GarysStudent's answer should do the trick for you!